# How can I show navigation route to a fixed location from current location?

Tags: java, android, mapbox, latitude-longitude, marker

This is my code which shows route to some point from curent location of user to that point....

My code works fine...

My current code shows route when marker is added after onclick event occurs but what I want to achieve is if I have a predefined marker at fixed longitude and latitude which is defined as p1 variable in below code, then it should show the route from the current location...

```
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
import androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView;
import com.mapbox.android.core.permissions.PermissionsListener;
import com.mapbox.android.core.permissions.PermissionsManager;
import com.mapbox.api.directions.v5.models.DirectionsResponse;
import com.mapbox.api.directions.v5.models.DirectionsRoute;
import com.mapbox.geojson.Feature;
import com.mapbox.geojson.Point;
import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.Mapbox;
import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.geometry.LatLng;
import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.location.LocationComponent;
import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.location.modes.CameraMode;
import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapView;
import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapboxMap;
import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.Style;
import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.style.layers.SymbolLayer;
import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.style.sources.GeoJsonSource;
import com.mapbox.services.android.navigation.ui.v5.NavigationLauncher;
import com.mapbox.services.android.navigation.ui.v5.NavigationLauncherOptions;
import com.mapbox.services.android.navigation.ui.v5.route.NavigationMapRoute;
import com.mapbox.services.android.navigation.v5.navigation.NavigationRoute;

import java.util.List;

import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Callback;
import retrofit2.Response;

import static com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.style.layers.PropertyFactory.iconAllowOverlap;
import static com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.style.layers.PropertyFactory.iconIgnorePlacement;
import static com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.style.layers.PropertyFactory.iconImage;

public class ViewMapActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback, MapboxMap.OnMapClickListener, PermissionsListener {
    private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle actionBarDrawerToggle;
    private NavigationView navigationView;
    Toolbar toolbar;
    MapView mapView;
    MapboxMap mapboxMap;
    LocationComponent locationComponent;
    private PermissionsManager permissionmanager;
    DirectionsRoute currentRoute;
    NavigationMapRoute navigationMapRoute;

    LatLng p1=new LatLng(72.843214,19.018335);//this is the fixed marker cordinates which I want to use
    

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Mapbox.getInstance(this,getString(R.string.mapbox_access_token) );
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_map);
        mapView = findViewById(R.id.mapView);
        mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mapView.getMapAsync(this);

        toolbar=findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Navigation");
        Toolbar toolbar=findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        drawerLayout=findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        actionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(ViewMapActivity.this,drawerLayout,R.string.drawer_open,R.string.drawer_close);
        drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle);
        actionBarDrawerToggle.syncState();
        navigationView = findViewById(R.id.naivgation_view);
        View navView = navigationView.inflateHeaderView(R.layout.navigation_header);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {
        //        UserMenuSelected(menuItem);
                return false;
            }
        });

    }
    @Override
    public void onExplanationNeeded(List<String> permissionsToExplain) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onPermissionResult(boolean granted) {
        if (granted) {
            enableLocationComponent(mapboxMap.getStyle());
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Permission not granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            finish();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onMapClick(@NonNull LatLng point) {
        Point destinationPoint = Point.fromLngLat(point.getLongitude(), point.getLatitude());
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        }

        Point originPoint = Point.fromLngLat(locationComponent.getLastKnownLocation().getLongitude(), locationComponent.getLastKnownLocation().getLatitude());
        GeoJsonSource source = mapboxMap.getStyle().getSourceAs("destination-source-id");
        if (source != null) {
            source.setGeoJson(Feature.fromGeometry(destinationPoint));
        }
        getRoute(originPoint, destinationPoint);
        return true;
    }

    private void getRoute(Point originPoint, Point destinationPoint) {

        NavigationRoute.builder(this)
                .accessToken(Mapbox.getAccessToken())
                .origin(originPoint)
                .destination(destinationPoint)
                .build()
                .getRoute(new Callback<DirectionsResponse>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call<DirectionsResponse> call, Response<DirectionsResponse> response) {
                        Log.d("response inside fun", String.valueOf(response.body().routes().size()));
                        if (response.body() != null && response.body().routes().size() >= 1) {
                            currentRoute = response.body().routes().get(0);
                            Log.d("current route", String.valueOf(currentRoute));
                            if (navigationMapRoute != null) {
                                navigationMapRoute.removeRoute();
                            } else {
                                navigationMapRoute = new NavigationMapRoute(null, mapView, mapboxMap, R.style.NavigationMapRoute);
                            }
                            navigationMapRoute.addRoute(currentRoute);
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Call<DirectionsResponse> call, Throwable t) {

                    }
                });

    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(@NonNull MapboxMap mapboxMap) {
        this.mapboxMap = mapboxMap;
        this.mapboxMap.setMinZoomPreference(15);
        mapboxMap.setStyle(getString(R.string.navigation_guidance_day), new Style.OnStyleLoaded() {
            @Override
            public void onStyleLoaded(@NonNull Style style) {
                enableLocationComponent(style);
                addDestinationIconLayer(style);
                mapboxMap.addOnMapClickListener(ViewMapActivity.this);
            }
        });
    }

    private void addDestinationIconLayer(Style style) {
        style.addImage("destination-icon-id",
                BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), R.drawable.mapbox_marker_icon_default));

        GeoJsonSource geoJsonSource = new GeoJsonSource("destination-source-id");
        style.addSource(geoJsonSource);
        SymbolLayer destinationSymbolLayer = new SymbolLayer("destination-symbol-layer-id", "destination-source-id");
        destinationSymbolLayer.withProperties(iconImage("destination-icon-id"), iconAllowOverlap(true), iconIgnorePlacement(true));

        style.addLayer(destinationSymbolLayer);
    }

    public void startNavigationBtnClick(View v) {
        boolean simulateRoute = true;
        NavigationLauncherOptions options = NavigationLauncherOptions.builder()
                .directionsRoute(currentRoute)
                .shouldSimulateRoute(false)
                .build();
        NavigationLauncher.startNavigation(ViewMapActivity.this, options);

    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        permissionmanager.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    }

    private void enableLocationComponent(@NonNull Style style) {
        if (PermissionsManager.areLocationPermissionsGranted(this)) {
            locationComponent = mapboxMap.getLocationComponent();
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                return;
            }

            locationComponent.activateLocationComponent(this, style);
            locationComponent.setLocationComponentEnabled(true);
            locationComponent.setCameraMode(CameraMode.TRACKING);

        } else {
            permissionmanager = new PermissionsManager(this);
            permissionmanager.requestLocationPermissions(this);
        }

    }

    // Add the mapView lifecycle to the activity's lifecycle methods
    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mapView.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mapView.onStart();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        mapView.onStop();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        mapView.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLowMemory() {
        super.onLowMemory();
        mapView.onLowMemory();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        mapView.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        mapView.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }

}
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: What is the error? Can you include more details in your question and explain your use case and issue.

Answer (score 0):

In `onStyleLoaded()`, instead of calling `mapboxMap.addOnMapClickListener`, you should just put the code you have in the `onClick()` method, like this:

```
Point destinationPoint = Point.fromLngLat(p1.getLongitude(), p1.getLatitude());
if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

}

Point originPoint = Point.fromLngLat(locationComponent.getLastKnownLocation().getLongitude(), locationComponent.getLastKnownLocation().getLatitude());
 GeoJsonSource source = mapboxMap.getStyle().getSourceAs("destination-source-id");
if (source != null) {
    source.setGeoJson(Feature.fromGeometry(destinationPoint));
}
getRoute(originPoint, destinationPoint);
```